# How do I use Array.prototype.filter() inside a forEach loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, foreach

I've come across plenty of answers here about using the filter() method, however none of them covered using it inside a loop. I managed to work it out, however I thought it would be good to include my answer here in case anyone else has this problem.

I have two arrays of objects, *links* and *index*. Each object has two attributes, *href* and *text*.

```
var links = [
      { href: '/accessibility', text: 'Accessibility'},
      { href: '/accessibility/accessibility-statement', text: 'Accessibility Statement'},
      { href: '/accessibility/color', text: 'Color and Contrast'},
      { href: '/accessibility/images', text: 'Images'},
      { href: '/accessibility/inclusive-language', text: 'Inclusive language'}
  ];
  var index = [
    { href: '/accessibility-statement', text: 'Accessibility Statement' },
    { href: '/accessibility', text: 'Accessibility' },
    { href: '/accessibility/colour', text: 'Colour and contrast' },
    { href: '/accessibility/images', text: 'Images' },
    { href: '/accessibility/inclusive-language', text: 'Inclusive language' },
    { href: '/accessibility/keyboard', text: 'Keyboard' },
    { href: '/cookies', text: 'Cookies' },
    { href: '/get-started', text: 'Get started' },
    { href: '/get-started/project', text: 'Production' },
    { href: '/get-started/prototyping', text: 'Prototyping' },
    { href: '/styles/colour', text: 'Colour' },
    { href: '/styles/images', text: 'Images' },
    { href: '/styles/typography', text: 'Typography' },
    { href: '/working-on-your-project', text: 'Working on your project' }
  ];
```

I'm writing a function which parses the index array and removes the element when it finds a matching object in the links array. I can't do this directly because two objects with exactly the same attributes in JS are not considered equal, so I'm just basing it off the href attribute, which is fine.

```
function removeLinksFromIndex(links, index) {
  links.forEach(element => {          // for each element in links array...
    index = index.filter(entry => {   // filter out entries where...
        element.href == entry.href    // the href attributes match
    });
  });

  return index;
}
```

This code should do as the comments suggest, however it doesn't. All I'm left with is an empty array at the end. I've output the index at each stage and it is unchanged every time except for the last iteration where it changes to `[]`.

Comment: Also, I think this is as simple as `const result = index.filter(i => !links.some(x => i.href == x.href));` and doesnt have the potentially nasty side effects your answer does

Answer (score -1):

The code I had at first was close, but not quite correct.

Firstly, the filter method returns an array of objects where the object meets the specified criteria. So I want to return objects where `element.href != entry.href`.

Secondly, if we remove the curly braces from the filter function, the code will work. It doesn't work when the condition is on a separate line as before. I'm not sure why, but perhaps someone else can explain?

```
function removeLinksFromIndex(links, index) {
  links.forEach(element => {
    index = index.filter(entry => element.href != entry.href);
  });

  return index;
}
// This code works!
```

Comment: when you used `{...}` in the filter function, those `{...}` became the body of the function - and because it had no `return` statement, you were implicitly returning `undefined`, which is a falsy value so the filter fails and filters out everything. Without the curly braces, the arrow function will implicitly return the expression after the =>